# Null value while trying to send a DropDownList value to an ajax function in a Modal using MVC - Entity

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I'm creating a new MVC WebSite using EntityFramework and, on my _Layout.cshtml I'm calling a PartialView, which is a Modal to insert a record on a specific table.

The partial view contains the following DDL:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Currency, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
       <div class="col-md-10">
           <select class="form-control" id="CurrencyId" name="CurrencyId">
                <option value="">Select currency...</option>
           </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

It uses an autogenerated model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Property
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Property()
    {
        this.Attachments = new HashSet<Attachment>();
        this.BankAccountCorrienteProperties = new HashSet<BankAccountCorrienteProperty>();
        this.Contracts = new HashSet<Contract>();
        this.Photos = new HashSet<Photo>();
        this.Renters = new HashSet<Renter>();
    }

    public int IdProperty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdOwner { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PropertyType { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SquareMetersSize { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Garage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PropertyStatus { get; set; }
    public string ConstructionDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> RentOrSell { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Currency { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<BankAccountCorrienteProperty> BankAccountCorrienteProperties { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency Currency1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public virtual PropertyType PropertyType1 { get; set; }
    public virtual PropertyStatu PropertyStatu { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Renter> Renters { get; set; }
}
```

And to load the data into the dropdown I had to use Ajax as follows:

```
getDdlInfo("../Currency/ListCurrencies", function (result) {
$.each(result.data, function (key, item) {
    $("#CurrencyId").append($('<option></option>').val(item.CurrencyId).text(item.CurrencyName));
});

function getDdlInfo(path, callBackFunct) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: path,
    success: function (result) {
        return callBackFunct(result);
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
```

For then sending the value to the controller, where an HTTP Post is there to send data to database:

```
function createProperty() {
$.ajax({
    url: '../Property/CreateProperty',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        //TODO: Modal de propiedad cargada
    }
});
```

My problem here is that:
1) Whenever `createProperty()` goes into the controller, all data is there, except for the dropdown. It gets to the controller always null, no matter if I select a value or not and...
2) Is this the correct approach for this? Am I missing something? I tried using Razor DropDownList but I couldn't find the way to do it correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your model the property is called `Currency`, so your input's name needs to match that to successfully model bind. Changing the name on the input to `Currency` should resolve it.

`<select class="form-control" id="CurrencyId" name="Currency">`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It was just that. Amazing!!